# Throughput issue between two servers located in different data center, scp speed is slow

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

Based on network support, we have 10Gbps network link between DC.

Between these two servers based on network, we should get 100MB/Sec or something > 50MB/Sec but we are getting 6MB/Sec so looking for reasons.

Both Servers are Linux (RedHat Linux 7)

SeverA.Domain1.com ( connect to 10Gbps network)

```
ethtool em1
Settings for em1:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full 
                            10000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
                            10000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 10000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 13
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000000 (0)
                   
    Link detected: yes
```

Sever2.Domain2.com ( Connected to 1000Mb/sec)

```
ethtool em1
Settings for em1:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full 
                            10000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
                            10000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Transmit-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 13
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000000 (0)
                   
    Link detected: yes
```

scp speed from Server A to Server B < 6 MB/Sec

Ran iperf and qperf

qperf shows 15MB/Sec

```
qperf -t 60 -v ServerB.domain2.com tcp_bw tcp_lat
tcp_bw:
    bw              =  15.4 MB/sec
    msg_rate        =   234 /sec
    time            =    60 sec
    send_cost       =  20.1 sec/GB
    recv_cost       =  14.8 sec/GB
    send_cpus_used  =    31 % cpus
    recv_cpus_used  =  22.7 % cpus
tcp_lat:
    latency        =  17.3 ms
    msg_rate       =  57.7 /sec
    time           =    60 sec
    loc_cpus_used  =  29.9 % cpus
    rem_cpus_used  =  16.4 % cpus

iperf shows

iperf -c ServerB.domain2.com
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to ServerB.domain2.com, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 10.xx.xxx.xx port 29404 connected with 10.xx.xxx.xxx port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  48.6 MBytes  40.7 Mbits/sec
```

Why throughput is slow between two servers ? Is something wrong in server configuration or something on networking side.

strange thing is, if we reverse direction of test i.e. from Server2 to Server1, our scp speed is about 50MB/Sec so we are getting better throughout in reverse direction.

Suggestions please ? I am looking whether issue is in Linux Server configuration or something wrong on networking side.

Comment: Can you try doing a traceroute in each direction and see if the same path is taken? Sometimes the paths are asymmetric, for instance due to a configuration error on a router, and the speed in one direction will be slower than in the other.

Comment: Traceroute looks different from Server A to Server B vs Server B to Server A, however I am not networking person so don't know how to interpret results from these output. Will seek help from networking team to further diagnose issue.